# Angular 14 minor version upgrade breaks component tests where MAT_DIALOG_DATA is injected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Upgraded Angular from `14.1.1` to `14.2.10` and material from `14.1.1` to `14.2.7` and it caused the following issue when running the tests using the default karma runner, and I am clueless about what could have gone wrong, please advise.

The upgrade only touched the `package.json` and the `package-lock.json`, nothing else is different, and before it, none of these issues were present. Using the dev server, the application still does work.

So when running tests, only a smaller chunk of tests is recognized, ie. before we had ~2100 tests, now it says `Executed 337 of 338 (skipped 1)`.

This is the error is emitted to the runner console

```
Chrome 107.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught ReferenceError: notification_model_1 is not defined
  ReferenceError: notification_model_1 is not defined
      at Object.39751 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/modal-dialog/modal-dialog-notification.component.ts:67:53)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at Object.90444 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/modal-dialog/save-changes-dialog/save-changes-dialog.component.ts:2:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at Object.46488 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/modal-dialog/save-changes-dialog/save-changes-dialog.service.ts:3:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at Object.12375 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/common/services/dirty-form-guard-connector.service.ts:6:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at Object.86409 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/common/services/dirty-form-guard-connector.service.spec.ts:3:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
```

The strange thing with that is that all steps in the stack trace go through *imports* and *not function calls*. Just look at the line numbers, they are all in the first few lines of the file, where the imports are, starting from the spec. Without source maps, the stack trace goes trough webpack `require` statements.

The actual error (caught with *Pause on exceptions* in the devtool) is thrown in a constructor of a component which is used in a material dialog, so injects `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`, eg.

```js
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalDialogNotificationComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: NotificationModel,
  ) {
```

(With the source maps turned off, the `public data` input param of the constructor is called `notification_model_1`, which matches the stack trace above)

Here it gets event more strange: out of curiosity, I adjusted that constructor so that the input param `data` is of type `any`. This change lets this test to pass, and the number of recognised tests increases ... by a few. But new similar errors surface: stack trace goes through imports, actual error is in a constructor injecting `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`, can be resolved by changing the param type to `any`.
So I went and adjusted these types to `any` one by one, until all of the errors were resolved and all of the tests *reappeared*. Interestingly, not all of the constructors injecting `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` had to be adjusted, only 2/3 of them.

Relevant versions:

|  | before | after |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @angular/common, core, etc. | 14.1.1 | 14.2.10 |
| @angular-devkit/build-angular | 14.1.1 | 14.2.9 |
| @angular/cdk and co. aka. material | 14.1.1 | 14.2.7 |
| typescript (not changed) | 4.7.4 | 4.7.4 |
| karma (not changed) | 6.3.2 | 6.3.2 |

What else I have tried

- cleaned the repo, even checked it out again
- rolling back the upgrade fixes this
- using the application from the dev server and building it are OK

Please advise if you have any tips, even if for just debugging this further.

Comment: I had same issue ! 

Is there an official issue in github already? 

I struggled to identified the problem.

Actually when replacing the type you define in MAT_DIALOG_DATA by any it work, so it is a typescript error? 

Very strange problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing a similar error

```
Chrome Headless 105.0.5173.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught ReferenceError: i_metadata_details_service_1 is not defined
  ReferenceError: i_metadata_details_service_1 is not defined
      at Object.68746 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/metadata/shared/abstract/abstract-metadata.component.ts:58:82)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at Object.33413 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/metadata/class/class-metadata.component.ts:4:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at Object.7354 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/metadata/class/class-details.component.ts:5:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at Object.35730 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/test/metadata/class/class-details.component.spec.ts:7:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at webpackContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/test/ sync \.spec\.ts$:181:1)
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
Chrome Headless 105.0.5173.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 5 of 5 ERROR (0.02 secs / 0.009 secs)
```

and similar behavior with only a subset of unit tests (5 of 636) getting recognized.

I was able to narrow the problem down to the `@angular/compiler-cli` package.  The issue was introduced in version `14.2.1`. So if I change the version to `14.2.0` in `package.json`, the error goes away and all unit tests get recognized.

```json
"@angular/compiler-cli": "14.2.0"
```

It seems the only change in version `14.2.1` of `@angular/compiler-cli` is a dependency upgrade (`ng-packagr`) as seen here on
[GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1421-2022-08-26).

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction and thanks for the answer. Was not able to confirm the answer both because other priorities, but also because it took a while to realize that when changing dependencies with `npm install`, npm seems to randomly bump some packages' minor version (`^14.1.1` does allow that), and it did that to _some_ angular packages' versions too. So believed that I was using `@angular/compiler-cli@14.1.1` but didn't verify it in the package-lock, where it turned out to be `14.2.x`...